# Bash script which logs log in/log out event of users in real-time

Tags: bash, sh

I'm curious about bash script, which will write information to the file once any user will log in/log out to the system in real-time?

Can I check it by filtering of commands from `ps`

```
ps -eo user,command
```

But ho to do it in real-time?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to reinvent `wtmp(5)`? See `man 5 wtmp` and `man 1 last`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the authentication sessions events in `/var/log/auth.log` file. For your case, the following command can be used to view the changes in realtime.

```bsh
sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

If you want to filer the session information from this, you can use

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log | grep systemd-logind
```